# IdHTTPServer receive readable parameter

Tags: php, delphi, indy

I have an app made in Delpi XE2 that acts as a web server, that I need to pass POST/GET variables for it to process em.

To pass the parameter I use this code(php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php
$url = "http://85.59.95.216:8080?data='тест'";
$timeout = 10;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and then in delphi:

```
procedure TMain.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Accesing: '+ARequestInfo.Document);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Method: '+ARequestInfo.Command);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Params: '+ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams);
end;
```

and the response I get is:

```
Accesing: /
Method: GET
Params: data='ýýýýýýýý'
```

How can I convert it to something readable?

Sorry if this is an easy question, first time doing a web server in delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-ASCII characters are not allowed in URLs.  Your PHP code is telling Curl to send a UTF-8 encoded URL without encoding the non-ASCII octets in the required `%hh` notation.  Indy's default charset is ASCII (by design) so it will lose non-ASCII octets it receives.

On the PHP side, you have to use [`curl_escape()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php) or [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode reserved/forbidden characters in a URL, `CURLOPT_URL` will not do that encoding for you.

Then on the Indy side, you can use the `ARequestInfo.Params` property to accessed the **parsed and decoded** data if the `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` property is True. The `ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams` and `ARequestInfo.QueryParams` properties contain **raw unparsed** data that you would have to parse and decode manually.

**Update**
A better option is to use a `POST` request to send your data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. That allows a charset to be specified for the encoded data. `TIdHTTPServer` will then decode the data into the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.FormParams` property. Look at curl's `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` options to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted request.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, but if i encode the URI before sending to Delphi, and use ARequestInfo.Params i get this data='ÑÐµÑÑ', dont know what to convert this into...

Comment: You are putting non-ASCII data in a URL query string. URLs do not support Unicode - period. Even with using urlencoding, there is no way to specify the charset used by the encoded data (which in this case is UTF-8). Use a `POST` request to send your data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. That allows a charset to be specified. `TIdHTTPServer` will then decode the data into the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.FormParams` property. Look at curl's `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` options.